# How can I only use a specified sheet in Sheets.JS with XLSX.read()?

Tags: javascript, file, xlsx

I am trying to specify a specific sheet to parse but keep getting both of them when I load a file. The line I have looks like this:

`workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array', sheets: "Sheet2" });`

My question is what format do I use to specify a sheet (where I have "Sheet2")?

I am going solely off of the documentation on https://docs.sheetjs.com/#parsing-options at the bottom of the table. How do I properly specify the sheet I want to use? Is it a string, or a numbered index? I have tried both.

Thanks in advance.

SOLVED

Comment: Educated guess: `workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array', sheets: ["Sheet2"] });`

Comment: @thirtydot Thank you for the response, unfortunately this did not work :/ I also tried using the index as [1] and it did not work either.

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/5xzsw2t8/. If I give it an Excel file with two sheets, one of them being named `testsheet2`, it only shows results for that sheet in the (annoying jsFiddle) console. Your problem is something else.

Comment: @thirtydot This worked for me in jsfiddle. Thank you, I do believe it is something else.. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @thirtydot so I just realized it only runs in jsfiddle with no errors.. it still prints "{testsheet1: {…}, testsheet2: {…}}" in console when I try with my file.

Comment: There's not enough information here for me to help. I don't have your code, I don't have your file.

Comment: I was able to figure it out.. I assigned the second sheet to a new variable and that seemed to work for me. I apologize for the confusion and appreciate your help!